# Equality condition for Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality for random variables

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am unable to find the equality condition for $CS$ inequality for random variables $X$ and $Y$.

I started as follows:
Consider two RVs $X,Y$ and let $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then we define a non-negative random variable $$W=(X-tY)^2$$

Since $$E(X-tY)^2 \ge 0$$
Then we get:
$$t^2E(Y^2)-2tE(XY)+E(X^2)\ge 0 \tag{1}$$
Since the above inequality holds for all $t$ we have the discriminant of the above quadratic to be less than or equal to $0$.
So we get:

$$E(XY) \le \sqrt{E(X^2)E(Y^2)}$$

When the equality occurs above, it means that the discriminant is $0$.

So the LHS of $(1)$ is a perfect square and the real number $t$ exists for which the LHS of $(1)$ is exactly zero, given by $t=\frac{E(XY)}{E(Y^2)}$

But I am unable to come to a conclusion that $X=mY$ for some $m \ne 0$ as given in my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following fact: If $X \geq 0$ and $E(X) = 0$, then $X = 0$.

In your case, if $t^* = \frac{E(XY)}{E(Y^2)}$, then $E(X-t^*Y)^2 = 0$. That implies that $(X - t^*Y)^2 = 0$ and thus $$X = t^*Y = \frac{E(XY)}{E(Y^2)}Y$$

If $X$ is non-degenerate, then $t^*\neq 0$; otherwise, $E(W) = E(X^2) > 0$.